# How does this method produce the highest value from the array?

Tags: arrays

I don't understand how the code in this method to find the value of the highest key from the array works. What is the -1 assigned to the max variable doing?

```
    public long getMax() {
    int j;
    long max = -1;
    if (nElems == 0) return max;
    for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++)
        if (a[j] > max)
            max = a[j];
    return max;
}
```

The value 88 is returned from this array = [77 44 22 88 11 66 33

Comment: Assuming the array contains only non-negative integers, assigning -1 to `max` ensures that the first value in the array will be greater than it, so in the first pass of the loop `max` will be set to `a[0]`

Comment: Thanks Nick! I understand it now. I'm just delving into, for the first time, a book on Data Structures and Algorithms in Java by Robert Lafore and working my way through a few of the programming projects.

Comment: This is a hack and should not be used. If the max of the array is actually -1, it will yield the same result as an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Trace out the code.
This is assuming the array holds positive numbers.

The idea is to iterate over the array, from left to right, while keeping track of the max. So before iterating, we assign max to be -1 meaning this is the highest now (since we haven’t gone through the elements)

Then when the first element is encountered, which will obviously be greater than -1, we assign max to be the first element. Then we go through the second element (44) which is lower than the max (77) so we don’t change the max, and so forth. That’s how this works.

We could have assigned max to be the first element and then iterated but it’s good practice to start from the lowest possible value, when trying to find the max, and the highest possible value, when trying to find the min.

Comment: Thanks srv236, really well explained.